# gracefully exit from program spawned by powershell script

Tags: powershell

Lets assume I have the following script:

```
$originalPath=pwd
D:\code\ps1\misc\title.ps1 "dynamo db"

$CURPATH = "$PSScriptRoot\path.txt"
$DB_DIR= cat $CURPATH

cd $DB_DIR
java -D"java.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib" -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar
cd $originalPath
```

This script starts the java program correctly, however, when I hit CTRL+C, the last `cd` command is not executed.

Is this by design for powershell? Or can I change this?

Answer (score 2):

<sup>This answer applies up to at least PowerShell (Core) 7.3.5.</sup>

When you use <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> to abort an external program, the current PowerShell script (runspace) is invariably terminated too.

While you cannot generally *prevent* your script from getting terminated,<sup>[1]</sup>  you can *perform clean-up actions*, namely in the `finally` block of a [`try` / `catch` / `finally` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Try_Catch_Finally):

```bash
$originalPath = $PWD

# ...

try {

  cd $DB_DIR
  java -D"java.library.path=./DynamoDBLocal_lib" -jar DynamoDBLocal.jar

} finally {

  # This block is *always* executed, but limitations apply
  # if Ctrl-C was pressed:
  #  * Execution invariably ends with this block.
  #  * You cannot output to the success output stream or error stream,
  #    neither explicitly nor implicitly: doing so quietly and instantly
  #    aborts processing.
  #  * However, the *other* output streams *can* be targeted, namely with
  #    the following cmdlets (but note that except for Write-Host and Write-Warning, 
  #    producing visible output is opt-in):
  #     Write-Host, Write-Warning, Write-Verbose, Write-Debug, Write-Information

  cd $originalPath

}
```

Note the limitations with respect to what [output streams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams) you may target, described in the code comments above, which stem from the `finally` block executing late in the script-termination process.

Notably, attempts to use `Write-Output` or implicit success-stream output or `Write-Error` will *quietly abort* execution of the `finally` at that point, whereas `Write-Host`, `Write-Verbose` and `Write-Warning`, to name the most important ones, are safe to use.

---

<sup>[1] The only way to *intercept* <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> in order to *prevent* termination is via a custom *keyboard-polling loop*, after having set `[Console]::TreatControlCAsInput = $false` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76632261/45375) for an example.</sup>